# Why the debug logs are not showing executed workflows

Tags: debugging, debug

I would like to debug on workflows that are getting executed on changes to the Contact record. However, I am not able to see any workflow steps that have been executed during their creation in the debug logs anywhere. What could be the reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you watching the right user? Workflow log is based the user who modifies the data I think

Comment: Yes Lance I created log on my name and I am the one testing.

Comment: Have you got too many debug logs already?

Comment: no only one with today's date. Very strange, better will raise a case with SFDC support as I dont see any other reason.

Comment: I believe you must have done this, but Can you check if those workflows are activated?

Comment: With which user are you testing workflow, is this Site or Community user?

Comment: Yes the workflows are active and the User is sys admin

Answer (score 1):

Assign Debug Log Level of Workflow to `Finer` or `Finest` and re-run the process.

For more information to set debug log level, refer [Set Up Debug Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&language=en_US)

and [Debug level](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_debuglevel.htm)

Comment: I have tried by setting workflow level to  Finer and Finest but I did not see any change in the logs.

Comment: Is that time based workflows?

Comment: No Santanu. It has immediate actions - field update thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support!

I have raised a case with SFDC support regarding this issue. SFDC confirmed that this is a known bug and fix for this will be on October 17th, 2016.